# Touchpad lost gestures and touchegg requres hack?

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch

I've had some success getting my touchpad to be usable by configuring syclient (although it was surprising that this was necessary).

Reading around I find that many gestures have been removed from 13.04>>, but the underlying code that favours these (now non-existent) gestures is still there preventing touchegg from working. I should be able to get touchegg working by "hacking" unity, but as it turns out I'm getting compile issues.....

Is there another way of getting gestures working? Please....